# VB ASCB in LotusScript?

Tags: vb6, lotus, lotusscript, lotus-domino

Working on converting a Visual Basic SHA-256 encryption routine to work in LotusScript.

Is going well except for the VB's AscB command.

Found: "Use the AscB function to return the first byte of a string containing byte data."

Not finding way to do same in LotusScript.

See the LS CByte command comes close: "CByte returns an expression that has been converted to Byte."

Don't see way to have it return just the first Byte of the expression.

Any suggestions?

Derek

Comment: May I ask why you do not just use an encrypted field?

Comment: BTW: SHA-256 is not encryption. It is a one-way cryptographic hash function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AscB is only appropriate for strings in single-byte character encoding.  All LotusScript string data is Unicode represented in UTF16 double-byte encoding.

The LotusScript Uni() function returns a Long containing the integer value of the Unicode character.  Since the input is a double byte character, the value returned by Uni() ranges from 0 to 65535.  If you want to get the values of each of the two bytes, code like this will do the trick:

```
Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim s1 As String
Dim u1 As Long
Dim u2 As Long
Dim lowbyte As Integer
Dim highbyte As Integer
Dim b1 As Byte
Dim b2 as Byte

s1 = "Ʃ"    

u1 = Uni(s1)

lowbyte = u1 Mod 256
highbyte = (u1 - lowbyte) / 256

b1 = Cbyte(lowbyte)
b2 = Cbyte(highbyte)

Call ws.Prompt(prompt_ok,"test",s1 + " " + Cstr(Cint(b1)) + " " + Cstr(Cint(b2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Would Asc, LeftB and RightB do what you need?

In my testing...

```
Lenb("A") = 2

Leftb("A", 1) = "A"

Asc(Leftb("A", 1)) = 65

Leftb("A", 2) = "A"

Asc(Leftb("A", 2)) = 65

Asc(Rightb(Leftb("A", 2), 1)) = 0
```